# Space of Operators on a vector space

Tags: group-theory, linear-algebra

I am taking a course on Linear Algebra and Group Theory. So, we have a definition of an linear operator on a vector space, which is simply a map $O:\mathbb{V}\rightarrow\mathbb{V}$.
with properties,
1.) $ O|v\rangle = |Ov\rangle $
2.) $(\alpha O_1 + \beta O_2)|v\rangle = \alpha O_1|v\rangle + \beta O_2|v\rangle = \alpha|O_1v\rangle + \beta |O_2v\rangle$
3.) $O_1O_2|v\rangle = O_1|O_2v\rangle = |O_1O_2v\rangle \equiv O_3|v\rangle$
**I was wondering if these linear operators form a vector space by themselves**. Because if they do, then cause of third property the vector space of operators will have an automatic vector product and we can have an Operator algebra. (Algebra is defined for me in my course as a ring over a vector space with vector multiplication as second binary operation).

My resolution is something like, since the dual of vector space can also be understood in terms of linear maps from vector space to itself, the linear operators look exactly like those linear maps and therefore seem to elements of the dual vector space. But there is a multiplication operation on operators which is like a composition of maps and i am not sure if the linear maps are closed under composition i.e. ( $\lambda_1o\lambda_2 \equiv ?  \mathbb{V}\rightarrow\mathbb{V}$)
A follow up doubt can be **do the general operators on vector space (including non-linear ) form a vector space?**

I am curious to know more about operators on vector spaces, so any extra info which overlaps (even slightly) with my doubt above will be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: I believe this question is better suited for Math.SE. But does this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map#Vector_space_of_linear_maps answer your question already? For what it's worth, 1.) is not a definition but IMO confusing and superfluous notation at best. I guess it indicated that acting with $O$ on an element of $V$ yields another vector in $V$? But that is clear by declaring $O: V\rightarrow V$.

Comment: @Nephente Thanks, it did answered most of my question. I wrote 1.) just for completeness.

Answer (score 1):

The dual of a vector space $V$ is the vector space of linear maps from $V$ to its underlying field of scalars $\mathbb F$.

The linear maps from $V$ to itself also forma  vector space. This is isomorphic to the vector space of $n \times n$ square matrices with elements in  $\mathbb F$ (where $n$ is the dimension of $V$, which for the purposes of simplicity we will assume to be finite). To set up the isomorphism you have to choose a specific basis for $V$, but once you do this everything falls into place. Addition and scalar multiplication of linear maps correspond to addition and scalar multiplication of vectors.

As well as addition of maps, we can also introduce the second operation of composition of maps. Composition of linear maps corresponds to multiplication of their relevant matrices. As long as you restrict yourself to *invertible* linear maps/matrices then you can use this second operation to create a *group* of linear maps/matrices, which is the [general linear group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_linear_group) of degree $n$ over the underlying field $F$.

Comment: The set of all maps from $V$ to itself or any other vector space forms a perfectly fine (even though infinite-dimensional) vector space.

Comment: Okay, I understand the space of operators is a vector space and for finite dimensional V, it is isomorphic to GL(n,F). The dimension of operator vector space is $n^2$ for $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{R}$ right? with same motivation, can we say something about the space of non-linear maps from V to itself?